# Max value of datatypes in C

Tags: c, limit

I am trying to understand the maximum value that I can store in C. I tried doing `printf("%f", pow(2, x))`. The answer holds good until x = 1023. It says `Inf` when x = 1024.

I am sorry that it is a basic question but I am trying to understand how C assigns datatypes' sizes based on my machine.

I have a Mac (64-bit processor). A clear understanding that I have is that my processor being a 64-bit one, it will be able to do calculations up to the value (2<sup>64</sup>). Clearly `pow(2, 1023)` is greater than that. But my program is working fine till x = 1023. How is this possible? Is GNU compiler has something to do with this?

If this is a duplicate of other question kindly give the link.

Comment: pow() returns double, not int. search for "C++ max double"

Comment: @MitchWheat ... Please see my printf statement.

Comment: I was referring to your example of 2^64 ....Nevermind. you have an answer below.

Comment: search max double value and you'll know

Comment: Please document yourself about the difference between integers and floating point data types in C and C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C the `pow()` functions returns a `double`, and the `double` type is typically a 64-bit IEEE format representation of a **floating point** number.

The basic idea of floating point is to express a number in the same general way as e.g. 1.234×10<sup>56</sup>. Here you have a **mantissa** 1.234 and an **exponent** 56. C++, and probably also C, allows decimal representation for floating point numbers (but not for integer types), but in practice the internal representation will be binary, with a power of 2 rather than a power of 10.

The limit you ran up against was the supported range for the exponent in your compiler's representation of `double` numbers; probably 64-bit **[IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)**.

---

The limits of the various built-in integral numerical types are available as symbolic constants from `<limits.h>`. The limits of the built-in floating point types are available as symbolic constants from `<float.h>`. See the table over at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits) for more details.

In C++ these limits are also available via the `numeric_limits` class template from `<limits>`.

Comment: `<limits.h>` documents ranges of the basic integer types (and `<stdint.h>` documents the ranges of some other integer types); `<float.h>` gives the limits on the floating point types.  Also, `pow()` takes and returns `double` rather than `float` data.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks! I posted that a bit late in the night. Will fix. (As an aside, the other answer is much more accurate but didn't get any votes. Huh.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Done, I think. However, I'm still on my first cup of coffee today. Glad for any corrections!

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! Can't vote up as I need more rep. Sorry :)

Answer (score 3):

"64-bit processor" *typically* means that it can deal with integers that contain at most 64 bits **at a time** (i.e. in a single instruction), not that it can only process numbers with 64 binary digits or less. Using [arbitrary precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) you can do calculations on numbers that are arbitrarily large, provided that you have enough memory (and time), just like how us humans can do operations on big values with only 10 fingers. Read more here: [What is the biggest number you can generate using a 64-bit processor?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-biggest-number-you-can-generate-using-a-64-bit-processor)

However `pow(2, 1023)` is a little bit different. It's not an integer but a [floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) number (of type `double` in C) represented by a sign, a mantissa and an exponent like this **(-1)<sup>sign</sup> × 1 × 2<sup>1023</sup>**. Not all the digits are stored so it's only accurate to the first few digits. However most systems use binary floating-point types so they can store the precise value of a power of 2 up to a large exponent depending on the exponent range. Most modern systems' floating-point types conform to [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) standard with `double` maps to [binary64/double precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), therefore the maximum value will be

> 2<sup>1023</sup> × (1 + (1 − 2<sup>−52</sup>)) ≈ 1.7976931348623157 × 10<sup>308</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The maximum value for a `double` is `DBL_MAX`. This is [defined by `<float.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits) in C, or `<cfloat>` in C++.  The numeric value may vary across systems, but you can always refer to it by the macro `DBL_MAX`.

You can print this:

```
printf("%f\n", DBL_MAX);
```

The integer data types all have similar macros defined in `<limits.h>`: e.g. `ULLONG_MAX` is the biggest value for `unsigned long long`. If printing with `printf` make sure to use the correct format specifier.